# Get filepath of active editor in Eclipse via cmdline

Tags: eclipse, command-line, eclipse-plugin, cmd

I want to know the filepath of the currently active editor in Eclipse from outside of eclipse. Using AppleScript doesn't work, but maybe there are other ways, like JMX, MBeans or something like that...?!

In AppleScript I would do something like...

```
$ osascript -e 'tell app "TextEdit" to return path of first document'
/Users/muhqu/Desktop/HelloWorld.txt
```

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do this unless you write an Eclipse plugin

Comment: @greg-449 maybe there is already a plugin that enables such a feature. e.g. some remote control stuff or something... But I haven't found anything yet. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way by using Eclipse's window title. The window title includes the path to the current workspace and also the package-relative path of the current active file.

```
FILEPATH="$(find "$WORKSPACE" -path '*'"${PACKAGE_RELATIVE_FILEPATH#*/}")"
```

For the complete script see [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/muhqu/57e0c0682918c23530a1).